# How show a few images on popup in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

I am working project in bootstrap. Can anyone please tell me How popup a few images on popover in Bootstrap ?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="More pictures"  data-full="http://placehold.it/50x50,http://placehold.it/100x100" >
     SHOW ALL IMAGES
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    placement: 'auto',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function() {
      // get the url for the full size img
      var url = $(this).data('full');
      return '<img src="' + url + '">'
    }
  });
});
```

this code just show one of images on popup i need to show all images...

[MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o3m1p9dv/)

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code to display all images

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  placement: 'auto',
  trigger: 'hover',
  content: function() {
  // get the url for the full size img
   var url = $(this).data('full');
   var partsOfStr = url.split(',');



  var img_html ='';
  for(var i = 0; i < partsOfStr.length; i++) {
   var element = partsOfStr[i];
   img_html += '<img src="' + element + '">';

   }
    return img_html;
  //alert(img_html);

   }
  });
  });
```